# Proper practice for cloning git repository for use in another project?

Tags: git

I have a simple 'Starter' repository that I use as a foundation for my projects that is version controlled in a git repository that I occasionally work on and update itself.

Is the correct methodology, when starting a new project, as follows (assuming local file system):

1. Clone the 'Starter' repository into 'New Project'
   `git clone /path/to/starter /path/to/new-project`
2. Remove the origin from the clone
   `git remote rm origin`
3. Add the new remote
   `git remote add origin git@remote.org:account/newproject.git`

If I am to do an update on the original 'Starter' repository, is there any way to bring those changes into my new project?

--

In case it is of any relevance, my 'Starter' repository is a Wordpress install with a number of customizations, plugins, Zurb Foundation etc...

Comment: Depends on whether you want to lose the association with the original repo, though I can see why you might want to do that. This is one of the problems with Wordpress - it's hard to pull upstream changes without breaking your current project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replicate your current workflow, but still allowing pulling updates from changes to your upstream "Starter" repository, you could start with:

```
git clone -o starter /path/to/starter /path/to/new-project
```

This will name the initial remote `starter` instead of `origin`.  Then add your upstream for your new project:

```
git remote add origin git@remote.org:account/newproject.git
```

If you want to pull changes from "Starter" you can:

```
git pull starter master
```

Otherwise, you can just use your `origin` remote as usual.